# LaTeX font for ancient Greek music notation?

Tags: fonts, greek, music

is there a font which contains the signs for ancient Greek music notation (unicode range 1D200 - 1D24F)?

Thanks

Rudolf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You could try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: For example: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/Musica.zip And then use `lualatex` or `xelatex`

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\grmusic{Musica.ttf}
\begin{document}
Greek music symbols:

\grmusic
\char"1D200
\char"1D201
\char"1D202
\char"1D203
\char"1D204
\char"1D205
\char"1D206
\char"1D207

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative fonts are: Aegean, Alexander, ALPHABETUM Unicode, Aroania, Avdira, Cardo, EversonMono, and New Athena Unicode

Comment: Also the Cardo font has the glyphs.